# How do I set video thumbnail as first frame of video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to see thumbnail in google photos which show first frame as thumbnail

Most answers (for example [FFMPEG add image at beginning of MP4 as first frame](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28853/ffmpeg-add-image-at-beginning-of-mp4-as-first-frame)) fail becouse I am on windows and do not have files like anullsrc or with error similar to:

`[AVFilterGraph @ 000002085fc0e100] No such filter: '[0:v]'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`

I know I can get thumbnail extracted using `ffmpeg -i [VIDEO] -map 0:v -map -0:V -c copy [IMAGE]`, but it would be better for me if it could be done in one command (cmd or powershell) so it would not leave lot of files behind when doing for many files.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking, do mean: Adding a frame at the beginning of the video, that can also been seen somewhere in the middle of video? So in google photos it is the thumbnail? Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I Will try to clarify: Google photo shows first frame of video. I discovered after writing this, that Thumbnail which players show is simply second video stream which Is not visible consisted of one photo with lenght of video.